# WPF UserControl with multiple Children

Tags: wpf, user-controls, children

I have a UserControl that I would like to be able to have more than one child.  It already has StackPanel as it's child, so what am I doing wrong?

Ultimately, I'd like for the control to include some of its own children automatically and then, when it's used, allow placing more children inside one of its elements.  I tried [MSDN's How to Override the Logical Tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742244.aspx) without success.

Thanks in advance.

LayerPanelItem.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Controls.LayerPanelItem"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
 <StackPanel></StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Main.xaml:

```
<controls:LayerPanelItem>   
    <TextBlock>Test</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock>Test</TextBlock> <!-- Error:  The property 'Content' is set more than once. -->
</controls:LayerPanelItem>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this (directly) with a UserControl.  Instead, you'll need to derive from [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx), and put your own custom layout logic in the subclass.

Comment: Reed is correct.  Here's why you can't do it:  When the XAML in LayerPanelItem.xaml is processed, UserControl's Content property is set.  So you are effectively trying to use Content for two different purposes.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add Grid in your `UserControl` and add rest of child to that grid.